# LyX: Configure a command for 3x3 determinant

Tags: lyx, matrices

I've been trying to add a new command to LyX to easen my way through physics, when mostly 3x3 determinants are used.

I clicked `Document` -> `Settings` -> `Preamble` and wrote the following:

```
% det 3x3
\newcommand{\ninedet}{$\begin{vmatrix}\\
\\
\\
\end{vmatrix}$}
```

Now, there are a few problems:

1. I understand that this code is supposed to make a 3x1 det, not 3x3.
2. It doesn't seem to work either way.

Thoughts? Any help would be deeply appreciated. `:)`

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 4):

I do not see the need of defining something new. With following approach, LyX will make use of the `vmatrix` environment automatically.

Use "Insert > Math > Matrix..." or alternatively, *in math mode* the toolbar to create an empty 3x3 matrix possible with some decoration like "`|...|`". Then you can copy and paste this matrix (either empty or already filled) to other locations in the document.

[image]